# mysql if count is null then make it zero

Tags: php, mysql

How do I set the field most_popular to 0 if its count is null with a select statement inside a select statement

i've tried IFNULL(SELECT COUNT(*) ...), 0) as most_popular but it won't work and I tried 
COALESCE(SELECT COUNT(*) ...., 0) as most_popular

```
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT *,         
    i.medium_image, i.width, i.height, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_details od WHERE od.product_id = p.product_id) as most_popular

    FROM products p 
        INNER JOIN product_images i on i.product_id = p.product_id      
    WHERE p.department_id=:department_id AND p.is_active=1
    $orderby        
    LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
```

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) ... ` never produces `NULL`. Try [`IF(bool, val_if_true, val_if_false)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) expression.

Comment: Can you give me example with the code I have with that IF(bool, val1, val2) statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT  *, 
        i.medium_image, 
        i.width, 
        i.height, 
        COALESCE(s.totalCount, 0) most_popular 
FROM    products p 
        INNER JOIN product_images i 
            ON i.product_id = p.product_id 
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  product_id, Count(*) totalCount
            FROM    order_details
            GROUP   BY product_id 
        ) s ON s.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE  p.department_id = :department_id 
       AND p.is_active = 1 
$orderby 
LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset
```

or how about this, (*your current query*)

```
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM order_details od 
          WHERE od.product_id = p.product_id), 0) as most_popular
```

Comment: I get no records and an error but it says Call to a member function fetchColumn() on a non-object

Comment: you're second attempt worked I don't know why it didn't work for me when I wrote the same code but without brackets at the start of the statement and at the end. Do you need brackets at the start and end. e.g. COALESCE((SELECT ....), 0) instead of COALESCE(SELECT ...., )

Comment: I wanted to upvote you earlier but you deleted it! Here's a fiddle just because. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77842/1

Comment: @KDM yes, because it needs a value not an expression.